# Connecting local data to Docker Django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, docker, plotly-dash

This is a question to understand what should be the best practice to follow in order to connect the dots on the argument. Currently I am developing a *Dockerized Django* website. In this website, one of the apps will be named 'dashboards', where I wish to publish data which is currently stored locally in `.csv` (updated every day through scheduled tasks).

Now, I am trying to understand what should be the next steps to follow in order to connect these data to the *Dockerized Django* website. My first guess would be to schedule locally `.sql` scripts to 'append' the new data into the db that I can create locally. Then, connect the db to the *Dockerized Django* website through *volumes* belonging the postgreSQL service. Just a guess that I need to test. But, is there a way to skip everything locally and just do the work inside my *Docker container*?

You can find the Github repository [here](https://github.com/PietroAminPuddu/docker-Django-Redis-PostgreSQL-PgAdmin-Nginx). Many thanks!

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    links:
      - postgres:postgres
      - redis:redis
    volumes:
      - web-django:/usr/src/app
      - web-static:/usr/src/app/static
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DEBUG: 'true'
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn docker_django.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - web-static:/www/static
    links:
      - web:web

  postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:latest
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "5050:80"
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: pgadmin4@pgadmin.org
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: admin
    restart: unless-stopped

  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - redisdata:/data

volumes:
  web-django:
  web-static:
  pgdata:
  redisdata:
```

Dockefile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN python -m pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```